# ¿Pueden las palabras "culto" y "secta" ser sinónimos?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, sinónimos

Varias veces he visto la palabra *culto* usada en una forma similar a la palabra *secta*. Sin embargo, cuando busco sus significados, no puedo encontrar ninguno que haga referencia a un grupo de personas.

El más parecido que encontré en relación con tener una connotación religiosa es:

> [**culto**](https://es.oxforddictionaries.com/definicion/culto)
>   Conjunto de actos y ceremonias en los que se expresa veneración y respeto a un ser divino o sagrado.

¿Existe entonces alguna definición que desconozca de la palabra *culto* que pueda ser utilizado como sinónimo de la palabra *secta*?

Comment: ¿En qué contextos viste la palabra usada así? Se me ocurre que en ocasiones puede haber una mala traducción o un calco del inglés, ya que *cult* significa "secta".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No son sinónimos, de hecho su uso como tal puede ser malentendido.

Creo que el problema radica en que no sean sinónimos en significado, sino que su uso similar ha llegado a homologarlas.

Un culto se refiere a la practica y veneración, mientras que la secta es la organización de personas que las practican.

Ambos son independientes los unos de los otros, pero para que haya una secta, debe haber como mínimo un culto.

La iglesia (secta) cristiana y el cristianismo no son lo mismo.

El nazismo y la supremacía de la raza tampoco son lo mismo.